# Hiding subsections of a timeline based on current slide?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a timeline for my product tour that has 4 main sections, with 4-5 subsections in between, it is set up like this:

```
<ul class="slideshow-timeline">
    <li class="active-target-main main-section"><a href="#target">Target</a>
        <ul class="current-section target-sub">
            <li><a href="#target-1">Donor Profiles</a></li>
            <li><a href="#target-2">Segmentation</a></li>
            <li><a href="#target-3">Custom Lists</a></li>
            <li><a href="#target-4">RFM Analysis</a></li>
            <li><a href="#target-5">Wealth Screening</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="main-section"><a href="#connect">Connect</a>
        <ul class="current-section connect-sub">
            <li><a href="#connect-1">Email Marketing</a></li>
            <li><a href="#connect-2">Social Media</a></li>
            <li><a href="#connect-3">Direct Mail</a></li>
            <li><a href="#connect-4">Welcome Series</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="main-section"><a href="#convert">Convert</a>
        <ul class="current-section convert-sub">
            <li><a href="#convert-1">Donation Forms</a></li>
            <li><a href="#convert-2">Automated Receipts</a></li>
            <li><a href="#convert-3">Events</a></li>
            <li><a href="#convert-4">Member Mgmt</a></li>
            <li><a href="#convert-5">Moves Mgmt</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="main-section"><a href="#optimize">Optimize</a>
        <ul class="current-section optimize-sub">
            <li><a href="#optimize-1">Analytics</a></li>
            <li><a href="#optimize-2">Campaigns/Funds/Appeals</a></li>
            <li><a href="#optimize-3">A/B Testing</a></li>
            <li><a href="#optimize-4">Task Management</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I am looking for a `JS` solution to allow me to hide the `connect-sub`, `convert-sub`, and `optimize-sub` while the `.active-tour` div has a class of `target-panel`.

I attempted this by using `.css` but was wondering if there would be a more-elegant solution?

```
$(function() {
if($('.active-tour').hasClass('target-panel')) {
      $(".connect-sub").css("display", "none");
      $(".convert-sub").css("display", "none");
      $(".optimize-sub").css("display", "none");
}
});
```

Since the `timeline` and `slides` are set as `position:absolute` and `position:fixed` it is not sitting in the page flow, so I can't just target it in css.

In theory, this JS should work, but for some reason, it doesn't want to hide the 3 sub sections. No errors are being thrown either. [Here is my working page](https://preview.hs-sites.com/_hcms/preview/template/multi?template_layout_id=3862706608&is_buffered_template_layout=true&portalId=494351&tc_deviceCategory=DESKTOP).

I will continue looking into a solution, but if any of you could point me in the right direction, I'd really appreciate it!

---

Updated to hide all subnavs and show with javascript:

```
$(function() {
if($('.active-tour').hasClass('target-panel')) {
      $(".target-sub").css("display", "block");
}
});
```

Comment: Why not hide all the sections by default with display:none and then only show the active one? Easier to just show one element rather than show one and hide all the others at the same time!

Comment: I will try this, but I think I will run into the same problem of not being able to pick it up based on class name, Edit: Implemented this idea, but I still can't target it based on the active tab having the class :/

Answer (score 0):

Updated answer:

Use a containing div for both the main content and the footer timeline. Set the class on this outer div using jQuery and use css selectors to show the correct submenu items accordingly.

[updated fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/fshL5zu4/)

---

original answer:

Here's a quick and dirty way to do it:

```
$('.main-section').on('click',function(){
  $('.main-section').removeClass('active-tour');
    $(this).addClass('active-tour');
});

.current-section{
  display:none;
}
li.active-tour .current-section{
  display:block;
}
```

[fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/fshL5zu4/)

Comment: Although this does work (to an extent) I'm looking for a way to do it so just ending up on an `active-panel` with a class of `target-panel` will automatically have the `target-sub` showing, and hide the others, if that makes sense

Comment: Maybe this can better explain what I'm trying to do: I have **[this example](https://www-salsalabs-com.sandbox.hs-sites.com/fundraising-software/tour)** built as well, the problem with this one is that it utilizes 15+ copies of the timeline, 1 for each slide. Which of course is a terrible way to do that. I'm looking for a way to do it with only 1 instance of the menu.

Comment: nope, I still don't get it. If I click on the nav arrows the timeline disappears (and I can't get back to it).

Comment: What do you mean the timeline disappears?